# Three rows of letters, find the missing letter in row 2

Tags: logical-deduction

Row 1.    CGIKNUXY

Row 2.    ADOQR

Row 3.    B

In row 1, the pattern goes 3421
In row 2, this pattern doesn't work.

Comment: Is this a puzzle of your own creation?

Answer (score 3):

The rows correspond to

> the number of closed regions in each uppercase letter:
>  C *EF* G *H* I *J* K *LM* N *ST* U *VW* XY *Z*
>  ADO**P**QR - P was missing.
>  B